# NullPointerException while using Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

When i call `Parse` method getList("some column") i always get `NullPointerException`. What should i do to avoid it?
Here is some code

```
ParseObject someObj = new ParseObject("Some table");
someObj.put("some column", "some text");
someObj.saveInBackground();

List<String> someList = someObj.getList("some column");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), someList.get(0), Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show()
```

Comment: Could you post your ParceObject code ?

Comment: ParceObject is class from library. See on Parce.com

Comment: parce.com is unreachable i think you mean't parse.com, if so the class name is ParseObject and not ParceObject.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. Parse.com

Comment: If there are spelling errors in the code in your question, that suggests you copied it by hand, instead of copy/pasting. That's not a very good idea: it makes errors more likely, and errors make it hard to help you.

Comment: According to the documentation for `ParseObject`, the method `getList` should return `null` if the key doesn't exist or if the corresponding value cannot be converted to a `List`. Therefore the line `someObj.getList("some column");` could only throw a NPE if `ParseObject` doesn't work as documented or if `someObj` is null. But `someObj` can't be `null` at that point as it was instantiated using `new`. Are you sure you've posted all the relevant details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're not getting a `NPE` in `List<String> someList = someObj.getList("some column");` I think that `getList` is returning `null` and you're getting the `NPE` when you try to get the first element on this list in the follow line: `someList.get(0)`.

[In `ParseObject` api for android:](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/)

> `getList` returns null if there is no such key or if the value can't be converted to a List

So since you're setting a string `some text` value for `some column` key in `someObj.put("some column", "some text")`, you can't get this value as `List` using `getList("some column")`, so simply use `get("some column")` instead.

Comment: No, `someList.get(0)` would throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if it had size 0.

Comment: @pbabcdefp `getList` not returns a list of size 0, returns `null`, so `get(0)` on `null` object throws `NullPointerException` not `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.